# swift UIview removeFormSuperview

Tags: swift, uiview

this is a test code,I want to add uiview to storyBoard ,and wait 1 second, and remove it .but the uiview doesn't appear , the code is down

```
    var uiview1 = UIView()    
    uiview1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    uiview1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(uiview1)
    sleep(1)
    uiview1.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: sleep freezes the current thread which in this case is the main thread which also is the UI thread so your function will stop at sleep and after 1s continue.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` is not a good idea in this way. It will become totally unresponsive and   block. Use `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var uiview1 = UIView()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    uiview1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    uiview1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(uiview1)
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("dismissView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

  func dismissView() {
    uiview1.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```